Как с помощью socket io подключится по протаколу wss
import { io } from "socket.io-client"
const socket = io("wss://api.gateio.ws/ws/v4/")
socket.on("connect", (sock)=>{
    console.log('connect')
    console.log(sock.id)
})


const url = "wss://api.gateio.ws/ws/v4/";
const socket = io(url, {
    query: {
        transports: ['websocket'],
    }
});


socket.on("connect", (data) => {
    console.log('connected');
});

не один способ не работает, как правильно подключиться, подскажите, пожалуйста !

Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Но если вы хотите использовать wss напрямую, то зачем вам socketio тогда вообще?

Socket.IO облегчает жизнь, вам не нужно заботиться о проблемах, связанных с балансировкой нагрузки, разрывом соединений

Тогда подключайтесь так, как этого требует документация socketio, и не лезьте в wss

так я не могу найти это в документации

Но вообще самый главный вопрос — почему вы решили, что api.gateio.ws в принципе поддерживает подключение к себе через socketio?

я не знаю, я честно с сокетами, только пытаюсь начать работать, через ws работает, но бывает отключается от сервера, даже если посылаю команду пинг. Вот почитал, что socketio решает эту проблему. Решил его попробовать. А как проверить, поддерживает или нет, если в документации gate, ничего про это не написано

Чтобы socketio решал эту проблему, поддержка socketio конечно должна быть на сервере. Если не написано, значит считайте что не поддерживает
